Is there a standardized way to convert a string to an int in any base?
I am trying to create my own c function btoi(char *str, int base) that can take any base from 2 to 64. However after reading a bit I realise I might be opening a big can of worms.
I'm saying this because binary,octal,decimal,hexadecimal,base-32 and base-64 alphabets are either universal or well defined in rfc4648.
However despite my initial assumption that anything up to base-62 would be a continuation of 0-9 + A-Z + a-z alphabet, reading section-7 of rfc4648 set me aback as "regular" base-32 is A-Z + 2-7.
To complicate things further we also have padding as a problem.
My question is: Is there a standardized way to convert a string to an int in any base (up to 64)?
Or is it however I want to implement it?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol for up to a base of 36

No, there is no standardized way to convert a string to an int in any base. Even regular base-10 numbers can be converted to string in different forms: "42" in English "٤٢" (or maybe the other way around) in arabic or whatever!

Presumably the input string is in any base, not the int.

Binary, octal, decimal, hexadecimal and other integer representations in any radix have nothing to do with base-32 or base-64 data encoding schemes.

Re “My question is: Is there a standardized way to convert a string to an int in any base (up to 64)? Or is it however I want to implement it?”: (a) A standard is just a specification that multiple people have decided to use. Standards specifying a single way to do a thing are great, which is why we have many of them, so you can choose which one of the many ways is the way to go. (b) The standard you link to does not even specify one way to encode base 64, as it shows two different choices. (c) Standards are not laws; even if there is a standard, you can do it however you want to implement it.

Another example: BIP39 converts 11-bit values (0 to 2047) into a word (hopefully in English, but many languages availble); usually used with 12 or 24 words for crypto seeds.

You're misunderstanding what RFC4648 is for.
It's not dictating which characters should be used for a number in bases 16, 32, and 64.  It's showing three different ways to encode binary data in ASCII text.
In the case of base64, it takes 3 8-bit values, treats them as 4 6-bit values, then outputs ASCII characters.  Below is an example of this from the RFC:
      Input data:  0x14fb9c03d97e
      Hex:     1   4    f   b    9   c     | 0   3    d   9    7   e
      8-bit:   00010100 11111011 10011100  | 00000011 11011001 01111110
      6-bit:   000101 001111 101110 011100 | 000000 111101 100101 111110
      Decimal: 5      15     46     28       0      61     37     62
      Output:  F      P      u      c        A      9      l      +

The above shows how the bytes values 0x14 0xfb 0x9c 0x03 0xd9 0x7e are converted to the ASCII string FPucAgl+.
As far as what alphabet is considered standard for numbers in bases 2-36, the most common is 0-9 for the values 0-9 and both a-z and A-Z for values 10-35 (i.e. case insensitive).
The standard library function strtol already exists that will do this for you.
